# How to programmatically modify fields of taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

In D7, how do I programmatically add/modify fields to taxonomy terms? They are clearly fieldable and in UI I can add and edit fields in them just like I do in nodes but it proved to be no easy task in the code. Say I have a vocabulary named Fruit with terms like Apples and Bananas. I've added a field to it named `main_article_id`, so all terms have Name, Description and Main Article Id. When I create a node named Apples that has a reference to the Fruit vocabulary (`field_fruit`) and Apples term is selected, the code should update Apples term and set its `main_article_id` field to `$node->nid`. Here is my code:

```
//hook_node_insert fires after new node has been inserted into db
function MYMODULE_node_insert($node)
{
    $taxonomy_term_id = $node->field_FRUIT[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $taxonomy_term = taxonomy_term_load($value['tid']);
    if($taxonomy_term != FALSE)
    {
        //doesn't work
        $taxonomy_term->field_main_article_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $node->nid;
        taxonomy_term_save($taxonomy_term);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The column name for a field isn't always `value`; in the case of taxonomy term references it's `tid`, and in the case of node/entity references it depends on what module you're using.

For a field created using the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module the name is `nid`, and for one created using the [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module, it's `target_id`.

The following code should work a bit better:

```
//hook_node_insert fires after new node has been inserted into db
function MYMODULE_node_insert($node)
{
    $taxonomy_term_id = $node->field_FRUIT[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'];

    // $value['tid'] isn't defined anywhere in this function scope so I 
    // assume you meant to use $taxonomy_term_id here
    $taxonomy_term = taxonomy_term_load($taxonomy_term_id);
    if($taxonomy_term != FALSE)
    {
        $column_name = 'nid'; // Or 'target_id' if you're using entity reference            

        $taxonomy_term->field_main_article_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0][$column_name] = $node->nid;
        taxonomy_term_save($taxonomy_term);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right about `$value['tid']`, sorry for mistake in the code. But I don't use any modules to create my field. I just added it manually on the vocabulary Edit Fields page. I tried to look at taxonomy_term when editing it in the UI. Inside hook_taxonomy_term_presave($term) $term it looked like this in `print_r()`: stdClass Object ( [tid] => 20 [vid] => 6 [name] => Fruit ... **[field_main_article_id] => Array ([und] => Array([0] => Array([value] => 14))**)

Comment: Gotcha, that one should definitely be `'value'` then. The taxonomy term reference, though, will also definitely be `'tid'`, so maybe you just need to change that line (`$taxonomy_term_id = $node->field_FRUIT[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'];`) and not the other one

Comment: already done that. :-) Still it doesn't work. By the way I looked at the result `taxonomy_term_load($taxonomy_term_id)` produces, and it looked like this: stdClass Object(`[tid]` => 1 `[vid]` => 2 `[name]` => Apples `[description]` => `[format]` => full_html `[weight]` => 0 `[vocabulary_machine_name]` => fruit `[rdf_mapping]` => ...). My preciousss `field_main_article_id` is nowhere to be found (I can see it in UI perfectly though). Should `taxonomy_term_load` operate this way?

Comment: Sorry again, my bad. I was being stupid and looked to the wrong place, that's why I didn't see any changes in my taxonomy terms. Your code works. Thanks.

Comment: Should `taxonomy_term_save` also work for updating a term's parents? I'm trying to use it for this purpose, but I'm running into an issue with updating the data.

Comment: Updating in what sense @Brent? I can't think of anything on a parent term that should be automatically updated when a child term is saved

Comment: @Clive First, thanks for all the answers you've posted here in the past. You must be one of the top contributors. I'm actually trying to update the parents just once via hook_update_N. I tried doing this with the Term Merge module, but it's not working for me, Drupal runs out of memory.